# Default Tensorflow device on multi-GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

If I run a tensorflow model (e.g. cifar10) with one GPU on a multi-gpu platform, tensorflow creates and broadcasts (training/inference) data across all the  GPUs available. Since I set num_gpus to 1, it's running on only one GPU. However, I can see the same processes on other gpus as well. Is it intended? Is there any rationale for this? I quickly checked with other DL frameworks like Caffe, but the design/operation is different. Of course, I can specify `device` in the code level, but I'm curious. Also, this default design might be annoying for other users if the machine is shared.

```
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name:

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: 

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:2) -> (device: 2, name: 

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:3) -> (device: 3, name: ...



+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     67056    C   python                                       15623MiB |
|    1     67056    C   python                                       15499MiB |
|    2     67056    C   python                                       15499MiB |
|    3     67056    C   python                                       15499MiB |
|    4     67056    C   python                                       15499MiB |
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, at startup TensorFlow allocates almost all of the GPU memory on all devices that are **visible** to it. However, unless you specify otherwise (in a [`with tf.device():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) block, it will only place operations on the device known (to TensorFlow) as `"/gpu:0"`, and the other GPUs will be idle.

There are a couple of workarounds:

1. Set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` (or `1`, `2`, etc. as appropriate) before launching `python` to control which devices are visible to TensorFlow. This can also be configured using the `tf.ConfigProto` options [`visible_device_list`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef56133461079f28b61b5a83a62685051408aadb/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L56) when creating your first `tf.Session`.
2. Set the `tf.ConfigProto` option [`allow_growth=True`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef56133461079f28b61b5a83a62685051408aadb/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L39) when creating your first `tf.Session`. This will prevent TensorFlow from pre-allocating all of the GPU memory.